# Set Python calculating precision higher than 15 digits

Tags: python, binary, polygon, digits, pi

for a more precise overview about my problem please look here: 
[Polygonally calculate Pi](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30000958/calculate-pi-in-python-with-polygons)

I used `mpmath`, `decimal` and some other modules to display more than the standard amount of digits, but only the first 15 of them are correct - meaning that when I run my program calculating pi the rest after the first 15 digits is inaccurate.

Or if I say `mpf(1/3)` it prints `0.3333333333333331574563241647...`. Is there any way to let Python calculate with exact numbers?  It is very very important for me because my method will produce angles like `0.0000000000000000000000245331°`, for example, and if this will be rounded I've got a problem.

Another example I tried is to calculate `0.0001 + 0.0002 - 0.0003` with and without the `decimal` module. Without it printed `0.0` and with it gave some sort of `1.5223456224E-31`. I assume this problem is coming from the binary calculation of Python?

Do you know a language that can calculate it exactly or better how to realise it in Python?

PS: Where does the problem with the lack of precision after 15 digits come from?

Comment: Yes, it's to do with the binary representation of floating point numbers (this is **not** unique to Python, you simply cannot represent the infinite range of real numbers with a finite number of bits) - see e.g. http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E19957-01/806-3568/ncg_goldberg.html. If you're using rational numbers, consider [`fractions`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/fractions.html#module-fractions).

Comment: Maybe this guide http://floating-point-gui.de/ will be easier for you to read

Comment: I don't know if it will fit your issue, but have you already think to using fixed point operations ? As it, you'll just have to multiply by, let's say, 10^6 each angle, thus you'll have an increase precision. But, as you may notice, this just displace the problem...

Comment: Can I use a bignum to solve the problem?

Answer (score 0):

The problem is how you create your variables. When you do `mpf(1/3)`, Python first calculates `1/3` as a 64-bit approximation, and then `mpmath` converts that approximation o a higher precision, but the error is already present. You need to initialize your variables using exact arguments. `mpf(1)/3` should provide the expected results.